# how to pick page number from the text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I had data like this

```
var pageval = $('#grid')
 .load('/Dealer/AllClaims?page=5&__=634673230919806673 #grid', CallBackFunction);
```

I had to pick the data pagenumber i.e 5 from the above text as I need to give it to the *'data'*  in the ajax call.

What is the best method to pick *'page'*

Can any one please help me to find out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will do the work:

```
function getUrlVars(url) {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,  function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = getUrlVars(url)["page"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. here i am not getting the data from the location.href it is in pageval(var). I want to get the data from it.

Comment: Hi thank you for upddated post. My data may change now i had the data like $('#grid').load('/Dealer/GetDealerClaims/?id=13&searchtext=&sort=SlmgReferenceNumber&sortdir=ASC&__=634673418696666895&page=5 #grid', CallBackFunction). Now if i use the above function the for page the page number appears as "5 #grid', CallBackfunction...

Comment: URLs should not have no spaces, so it should be safe to split your string at the blank and take the first part as input for the function. Or try to edit the regex, you can ask for help in a new question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you can save the url string in a variable

```
var abc = "/Dealer/AllClaims?page=5&__=634673230919806673";

var pageNo = parseInt(abc.substring(indexOf('?page')+5, indexOf("&")));
```

Comment: Thats a bit too specific and will not fit in most cases.

Comment: Is that fine now?. I think its more generalized now.

Comment: Better, but will only work if "page" is the first and not the last argument

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a better option.